# Separate a list of files by keyword group, then sort each group by reverse date

Tags: bash, sh, ls

I use this:

```
for f in $( ls -tr ${repSource}*.txt );
```

...to loop on a list of files, sorted oldest to newest.

I want to add another sort "filter": filenames that don't start with "abc" come first, whatever their timestamp.

So if the files are "abc.txt", "def.txt"  and "ghi.txt", then "abc.txt" must be last, and the other two come before in the list (sorted by reverse date).

Comment: Use `find` with `stat` to output file's attributes and then use `sort` on those fields

Comment: I search on the net example with find/stat and then sort, i think i understand how it works, i will try it ! Thanks

Comment: I tried $( ls -tr ${repSource}*.txt | find . -type f -name "$masque*" | sort )
But i think "find" filter on files which starts with "$masque". And i don't really want to "filter" but i want to prioritize files which match with my condition.

To be more detailed, an other example, i wasn't clear in the first one :
I have in my repository 3 files, which are "abc.txt", "def.txt" and "ghi".txt 
and i want to specify to my "for" loop to read first files which doesn't starts by "abc" so i want it to read "abc.txt" in the last position

Comment: To be short, i want to read every files in my repository, but read first files which doesn't starts by "abc" for example. Or read last files which starts by "abc", which is the same idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out the very first item on this list: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to parse the output of the `ls` command.  The construct in your question is a classic [bash pitfall](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) and [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is well known to be problematic.

You can instead use `stat` to get the time of each file that you find in a `for` loop on a pattern expansion.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

uname_s=$(uname -s)

stamp() {
    case "$uname_s" in
        Linux)       stat -c '%Y' "$1" ;;
        Darwin|*BSD) stat -f '%m' "$1" ;;
    esac
}

inputfiles=( "$@" )

for file in "${inputfiles[@]}"; do
    n=$(stamp "$file")
    while [ -n "${forward[$n]}" ]; do
        ((n++))       # introduce fudge to avoid timestamp collissions
    done
    forward[$n]="$file"
done

declare -p inputfiles

for n in "${!forward[@]}"; do
        reverse[$(( 2**32 - $n ))]="${forward[$n]}"
done

declare -p forward reverse
```

This example script takes a list of files as command line options (which can be a glob), then uses `declare -p` to show you the original list, the forward-sorted list, and a reverse-sorted list.

The `case` statement in the `stamp` function makes it portable between Linux, OS X (Darwin), FreeBSD, NetBSD, etc. since I don't know what operating system you're using.  (If it's something less common like Solaris, HP/UX, etc, then the `stat` command may not be available or useful and this solution might not work.)

Once you have a sorted (non-associative) array in bash, you can process the files one by one with constructs like:

```
for file in "${forward[@]}"; do
    # something to $file
done
```

or

```
for file in "${reverse[@]}"; do
    # something to $file
done
```

And you can trust that since non-associative bash arrays are always numerically ordered, you'll get the files in their date order.

And of course, you've got the dates themselves as indexes, if you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

The files:

```
ls -log
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 4 Apr  8 11:15 abc.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 4 Apr  8 11:15 def.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 4 Apr  8 11:16 ghi.txt
```

This seems to work, but there must be a better way:

```
ls -log --time-style +%s | tail -n +2 | \
pee \
    'grep -v abc.txt | sort -k4 -rn' \
    'grep    abc.txt | sort -k4 -rn' | \
cut -d " " -f 5
```

Output:

```
ghi.txt
def.txt
abc.txt
```

Note: the unseemly named util **pee** is from *debian*'s **moreutils** package, it's a "like **tee** for pipes".

Now to make a loop of it:

```
# usage: foo filename   # filter above sort code by filename
foo() { ls -log --time-style +%s | tail -n +2 | \
        pee 'grep -v '"$1"' | sort -k4 -rn' \
            'grep '"$1"' | sort -k4 -rn' | \
        cut -d " " -f 5 ; }


for f in $( foo abc.txt )
```